# How to fill `nan` values from columns of same name within a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have dataframe (result of bad joining I suppose) which looks like this:

| Index | col_a | col_b | col_a | col_b | col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 62 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Second | NaN | NaN | 36 | 52 | NaN | NaN |
| Third | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 25 | 26 |

And I want to squeeze it such that same column names align having only one column each as in:

| Index | col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 62 |
| Second | 36 | 52 |
| Third | 25 | 26 |

It is guaranteed that there will be only one non-nan value for each row and column combination which I checked using a couple of `notna()` checks. There are infact a large number of columns and a large number of indices. I just posted a sample dataframe for simple problem reproduction. I tried looking at squeeze() and now trying to combine them via splitting and joining but far from an ideal solution

Comment: Dataframe with multiple columns with the same name? Fix the bad merge and resolve at the source.

Comment: I would if I could but this is how I am getting data from some people and I do not have control over how they export it. And yeah its most likely a result of a bad merge/join as I mentioned in the start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since at most one non-`NaN` value is guaranteed, use `groupby` + `first` along the columns axis.

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).first()

    Index  col_a  col_b
0   First    1.0   62.0
1  Second   36.0   52.0
2   Third   25.0   26.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try via `Transpose(T)` attribute,`dropna()` and `apply()` method:

```
df=df.T.apply(sorted,key=pd.isnull).dropna().T
```

output of `df`:

```
    Index   col_a   col_b
0   First   1.0     62.0
1   Second  36.0    52.0
2   Third   25.0    26.0
```